# How do I collect the center of the blobs in chessboard order?

Tags: python, sorting, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm using opencv in python to calibrate the lens.
I took a photo in different angles and locations like this:
[image: 56 LED dots in black background]

Then, I ran the blob detector in opencv.

```
import cv2
import numpy
img = cv2.imread('./image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.minThreshold = 50
params.maxThreshold = 255
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 0
params.maxArea = 80
params.filterByColor = True
params.blobColor = 255
params.filterByCircularity = False
params.filterByConvexity = False
params.filterByInertia = False

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

keypoints = detector.detect(img)
```

The detected blobs are shown in red circles like this.

[image: Detected blobs are shown in red circles.]

The object keypoints contains the center location of the detected blobs.
I collected the center location like this:

```
ips = []
for keypoint in keypoints: ips.append((keypoint.pt[0], keypoint.pt[1]))
ips = np.array(ips, np.float32) # image points.
```

What I want is, I want to store the center location of those red circles in order like cv2. findChessboardCorners.

[image: The order of the circles.]

So I defined a function that sorting along the horizontal axis first and then vertical axis.

```
def index_sorting_to_checkerboard(arr, shrinker):

    ind1 = arr[:,1].argsort()
    arr = arr[ind1]
    floored = np.floor(arr).astype(int)
    floored_shrinked = np.zeros_like(floored)
    std = floored[0,0]
    for i, (x,y) in enumerate(floored):
        if abs(y-std) <= shrinker: floored_shrinked[i] = (x, std)
        else: 
            std = y
            floored_shrinked[i] = (x, y)

    # sort by the second col, then the first column.
    ind2 = np.lexsort((floored_shrinked[:,0], floored_shrinked[:,1]))
    ret = floored_shrinked[ind2]
    ind3 = ind1[ind2] # An accumulation of all argument changes.

    return ret, ind3

shk, ind = index_sorting_to_checkerboard(ips, 30)
ips = ips[ind]
```

This function works when the image is low-tilted.
However, when the image is tilted a lot like:
[image: Tilted image.]

it does not works well.
That's because the vertical order of the blobs in the upper line can be lower than those in the next line.
That is, the vertical location of the blob 13 (upper right) can be lower than blob 14 (below the blob 0) when the images are tilted a lot.
So I have to change the value of 'shrinker' manually every time the new images are taken.

Can you suggest me better algorithm to sort in chessboard order that works regardless of the inclination?
I think it is possible because cv2.findChessboardCorners always returns the location in this order,
but I don't know how it does that.

Comment: Maybe if you get the four “corners” of the ball array (i.e., the top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right) you can tune out the algorithm. At the very least you should be able to rotate the whole image if you find the rotated angle before applying your existing solution.

Comment: Rotate the image so the array is more horizontal

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but rotating must be avoided. Because what I'm going to do is to obtain how much the image is rotated. 

Also, even if I rotate to make it horizontal, it means I have to manually check that the image is sufficiently horizontal after rotation. Since I want to automate the algorithm, sorting is the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your pattern is elongated, you can estimate the approximate directions of the two axes of the grid (e.g. with PCA).

Based on the estimated direction and the distance between points, you'll be able to search which point is next to a point.
So, it seems that the order of the points can be recognized.

Comment: Many years ago, I implemented point to point search method for fish eye camera calibration.
Since my pattern was N*N, the axial direction could not be estimated as in this answer, and the image distortion was strong(because target is fish-eye), but it almost worked.

Comment: Do you mean PCA for Principle Component Analysis? I searched it right after I read your comment, and I think it will work! I'll try it. Huge thanks to your comment.

Comment: Yes about "PCA". However I guess some more coarse way may convenient to first try.
e.g. if you find the most distant point pair, it probably corresponds to the diagonal of the grid. If you can get 2 diagonals with such easy way, axis direction can be estimated from them.